# Having error null value in column "publicatithon_date" violates not-null constraint in django

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm new to django and I'm learning django with this book:
djangobook.com
and I stuck in chapter 5 & 6 because when I try to check my work(in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/books/book/add/) I get some errors and I was trying to fix those errors and after that they gone but I got a new error and I tried to figure out how to solve it but I still don't know how.
This is my error:

> IntegrityError at /admin/books/book/add/
>
> null value in column "publicatithon_date" violates not-null constraint

And you can see all of my codes here:
https://github.com/Anahitahf/mysite2

How can I solve this error?
Thanks in advance for any feedbacks.

Comment: Please write ur errors and ur code where u got stuck

Comment: Note that the Django Book is extremely out of date. You could try [Mastering Django](http://masteringdjango.com/django-book/), which is an updated version for Django 1.8.

Comment: you can read this tutorial <http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/>. it is very basic and very good explanation and almost up to date.

Comment: I create some models then I go to admin site to see the result and add a book then I get this error and the models file is here:
https://github.com/Anahitahf/mysite2/blob/master/models.py
and admin.py is here:
https://github.com/Anahitahf/mysite2/blob/master/admin.py
When I try python manage.py runserver in terminal and go to this url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/books/book/add/
and try to save a book I can't and get the error.
In the end thanks for introducing the resources and yes one of my problems is that this book uses the old version of django while I'm using the version 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, the publication_date is a not-null field and you're trying to add a Book with publication_date not set.
One option to fix that is to make publication_date accept null values in your models.py thus:

```
publication_date = models.DateField(null=true,)
```

However, I think that the issue is being caused as you're trying to reload the page?? Anyhow, try to go back to the admin page and then try to create a new Book again. The error should not happen then. If it does, then you can set the null property of publication_date as true.

**edit:**
Going through your models you don't have a "publicatithon_date" field in them. Maybe you created that field by mistake and removed it from your model after making a migrations?? You should do the following in your terminal:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell 

$ mysql> | psql> ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column publicatithon_date;

$ python manage.py syncdb
```

And it will drop the wrong field from the table.

Comment: Thank you.
I solve the  problem by dropping the column and adding it again and now there is no problem with publication_date.
And I have to say that I need the publication_date column and I couldn't just drop it and don't add it again but anyway dropping it was a good idea and thank you again.